# how to create a separate record for each item in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, loops, controller

I have an app where a user can have several Friends and can create Groups of Friends. after the user has frist created a Group and is on the show page for this Group there is a form that displays a list of friends with a check box next to each of them. The user can select friends that will be added to the group and, on submit, a group_member item will be created to join each of the selected friends to the current Group.

```
<%= form_for @group_member, :url => {:controller => "groups", :action => 'add_member'} do |f| %>
  <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "friend_ids[]", friend.id %></td>
      <td><%= friend.name + friend.id.to_s %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => params[:id] %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This seems to be submitting all of the parameters needed for each group_member to the controller

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zg...Bg=", "friend_ids"=>["2", "3"], "group_member"=>{"group_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Create Group member"}
```

but I'm having trouble working out how I would write this action. I need to loop through the items in the "friend_ids" array and for each of them, create a new GroupMember item. Something to the effect of this (hopefully this will give you an idea of what i'm trying to do):

```
def add_member
  friend_ids.each do i
    @member = GroupMember.create(:group_id => params[:group_id], :friend_id => i.value)
  end
end
```

can this be done in the way i'm trying and if so is that even a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
def add_member
  group_members_attributes = []
  params[:friend_ids].each do |id|
    group_members_attributes <<({ :group_id => params[:group_member][:group_id], :friend_id => id })
  end
  GroupMember.create group_members_attributes
end
```

This will build an array of hashes that will then be used to bulk create all the GroupMembers in a single database insert rather than 1 database insert per friend_id.